# add custom webpi feed programmatically

Tags: web-platform-installer

Is it possible to add custom feed programmatically to Web Platform Installer? I tried adding the feed manually and found that the feed location is stored in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\web.preferences file. However the file seems somewhat cryptic and I would not like to modify it manually. Is there any API for that?

Update: even if this web.preferences file could be edited it is not the way to go as it is user specific file and I need system wide configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this link](http://forums.iis.net/post/1980965.aspx),

> Sorry, there isn't a way to do that currently (for security reasons,
>   we don't allow an untrusted feed to be loaded without the user's
>   consent)
>
> Once the feed is added via the Options dialog, it does persist between
>   sessions

I think we can't add custom feed without intervene from user. Maybe you can use WebpiCmd.exe
 that can be configured programmatically via scripts.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer>WebpiCmd.exe /List /Feeds:http://yourcustomwpifeed.co.id/customFeed.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe it may interest others. You can modify the file *%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\webpi.preferences*. Yes, it is a little cryptic, but [here's my post about how to do it](http://mhusseini.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/modify-web-platform-installer-configuration-with-c/).

The file *webpi.preferences* is user-specific. If you want to set settings for all users, all I can think of is to write a bootstrapper application that first modifies *webpi.preferences* (using the code in the post) and then runs *WebPlatformInstaller.exe*.